How can I find out what my sudo password is on SteamOS?
I'm trying to install an app on SteamOS and it's through the Terminal. When I run the command, I need to enter my sudo password as can be seen below:


The thing is, I’ve never set a sudo password as far as I’m aware.
How can I find out what this password is, maybe change it or remove it?
I really don’t know what I set my sudo password to, I have no memory of ever setting one.
I found this answer, but it didn't help me as when I enter those commands, then it asks for the sudo password again which I don't have.

Steam OS Accounts

SteamOS comes with two predefined accounts. The first is "steam" and it is the account where Steam and all its games run. This is a non-privileged account. The second account is "desktop" and this is where the SteamOS desktop and any non-Steam applications run. This account can use 'sudo' to gain administrative privileges after you set a password for it.
Please note: These are SteamOS accounts and are not associated with any Steam Login. Multiple Steam users may login and access Steam, however, all users will be sharing the same SteamOS desktop and accounts.

How to gain root access
The desktop account can gain root access, however has no password when shipped.
Before you can use this account to gain root access, you need to assign a password.
From the desktop session, start a terminal window and type passwd.
Enter your new password twice.
Now you can use the sudo command to perform privileged operations.
Steam OS Accounts
You can also try:

You can also try to use sudo su and enter the current user's password.


With passwd, whatever you enter as the password is...the password! For security reasons, they don’t set a default password...that would open up every user to all sorts of attacks. If you need to set a password for sudo to work, then:
Make sure you’re running commands as the superuser: `su desktop'
Then run a command to set a password: passwd
After that, whatever password you set should be the password that enables access to sudo.

SteamOS root password.
What is the default password for SteamOS?

The Steam Deck runs SteamOS, which is a fork of Arch Linux. On the latter, the default root password is root, while on SteamOS it isn't set. The same goes for the default Steam Deck user (deck), which also doesn't have a password

